# $\mathbb{K}[x,y] /( xy - 1)$ has infinitely many prime ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, localization

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field. Then $ \mathbb{K}[X,Y] /(XY- 1)$ has infinitely many prime ideals.[True/False].

What happens when $\mathbb{K}=  \mathbb{C}?$

What I know is that, the prime ideals in $\mathbb{K}[X,Y] /(XY- 1)$ are in one-one correspondence with the prime ideals in $\mathbb{K}[X,Y] $ containing the ideal $(XY-1).$

Can we use the result here?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: what happens if you take some irreducible polynomial in one variable?

Comment: If $\mathbb{K}$ is a finite field, for example $\mathbb{F}_2$ a.k.a $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, then this problem becomes easier to solve.

Comment: Can you please give some more details?

Comment: I know that , $XY - 1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{K}[X,Y]$.

Comment: @BenediktArnarsson: I am intrigued by your comment. To my mind, the problem is easier to solve when $\Bbb{K}$ is infinite (so that  for each non-zero $a \in \Bbb{K}$, the kernel of the homomorphism such that $X \mapsto a$ and $Y \mapsto a^{-1}$ is a prime ideal that is uniquely defined by $a$).

Comment: So for each non-zero $ a \in \mathbb{K}$ , $A_{a}= (X-a) ( aY-1)$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{K}[X,Y]$. But how can we show that $a \neq b$ imply $A_{a} \neq A_{b}$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\mathbb{K}[X,Y]/(XY-1) \cong \mathbb{K}[X]_X$. This last ring is the one obtained by inverting $X$ in $\mathbb{K}[X]$. Thus, the prime ideals of $\mathbb{K}[X,Y]/(XY-1)$ are in bijection with those of $\mathbb{K}[X]_X$. Moreover, the prime ideals of $\mathbb{K}[X]_X$ are in bijection with those of $\mathbb{K}[X]$ that do not contain $X$. Now, the only prime ideal of $\mathbb{K}[X]$ that contains $X$ is $(X)$. (This is because $(X)$ is in fact maximal.)

We conclude that, if $\mathbb{K}[X]$ has infinitely  many prime ideals, then $\mathbb{K}[X,Y]/(XY-1)$ also has infinitely many prime ideals.

Comment: $K[X]$ always has infinitely many prime ideals.

Comment: @user26857 indeed, and so we are done.